# Windows 8 cmd %PATH% tab completion

Tags: command-line, windows-8, tab-completion

I have to assume I was confused about the directory I was working in, but when I initially installed Win8, I would swear that I had %PATH% tab completion.  As in >pi <kbd>tab</kbd> becomes >ping.  Was I dreaming, or did I do something since then that broke it?

Comment: This is true for the Powershell console, but not I pelieve for cmd.

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to find items even when they’re not in the current directory? If so, then no, there’s no way to do that with the command-prompt, but you could try a third-party version like Console2 or something (I don't think they support that either, but you could try requesting the feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using PowerShell, Command Prompt doesnt support tab completion natively.

Comment: Well, it was a while ago, and I suppose I could have confused my memory.  I don't like powershell so much, so I don't know why I would have been using it.  Oh well.